# Referring to the type of an inner class in Scala

Tags: scala, types, inner-classes

The following code tries to mimic [Polymorphic Embedding of DSLs](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~ko/papers/gpce50_hofer.pdf): rather than giving the behavior in `Inner`, it is encoded in the `useInner` method of its enclosing class. I added the `enclosing` method so that user has only to keep a reference to `Inner` instances, but can always get their enclosing instance. By doing this, all `Inner` instances from a specific `Outer` instance are bound to only one behavior (but it is wanted here).

```
abstract class Outer {
  sealed class Inner {
    def enclosing = Outer.this
  }
 def useInner(x:Inner) : Boolean
}

def toBoolean(x:Outer#Inner) : Boolean = x.enclosing.useInner(x)
```

It does not compile and scala 2.8 complains about:

```
type mismatch; found: sandbox.Outer#Inner
               required: _81.Inner where val _81:sandbox.Outer
```

From [Programming Scala: Nested classes](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch05.html#NestedClasses) and [A Tour of Scala: Inner Classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/115), it seems to me that the problem is that `useInner`expects as argument an `Inner` instance from a specific `Outer` instance.

What is the true explanation and how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose the type Inner is like the type this.Inner. Outer#Inner is independent of the outer instance (not a path-dependent type).

```
abstract class Outer {
  sealed class Inner {
    def enclosing = Outer.this
  }
  def useInner(x:Outer#Inner) : Boolean
}

def toBoolean(x:Outer#Inner) : Boolean = x.enclosing.useInner(x)
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify toBoolean instead of useInner?

Comment: If tried `def toBoolean(x: y.Inner forSome{val y : Outer}) : Boolean = x.enclosing.useInner(x)` (Existential Types - Existential Quantification over Values from the Scala reference) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is as you describe, that `useInner` is expecting an `Inner` of a specific `Outer` instance. Since `enclosing` returns a generic `Outer`, there is really no way to tie both together that I know of.

You can force it, however:

```
def toBoolean(x: Outer#Inner): Boolean = {
  val outer = x.enclosing
  outer.useInner(x.asInstanceOf[outer.Inner])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define your member like this:

```
def useInner(x:Outer#Inner) : Boolean
```

Or you can write like this:

```
abstract class Outer {
    class InnerImpl {
        def enclosing = Outer.this
    }
    final type Inner = Outer#InnerImpl
    def useInner(x:Inner) : Boolean
}
```