# Scala Inner Class - Not a Member

Tags: android, scala

I am trying to create a variable of type [MulticastLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html), which is an inner class defined within the Android framework.

However, I am receiving an error stating that MulticastLock is not a member of WifiManager.

Do I need to reference an inner class differently in Scala?

```
var multicastLock:android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock = null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `WifiManager` is a *class*, then you need to use `#` instead of `.`.  But be aware that this is not just an idle syntactic difference; when you have an inner class of an outer class, it can matter *which instance* of the outer class it came from.  The `#` alerts you to the fact that there is this new issue (`X#Y` is the type of the inner class belonging to any copy, not a specific copy; if `x` is an instance of `X`, then `x.Y` is the type of an inner class of that particular instance).  There are other questions here that deal with different use cases of inner classes (e.g. [Referring to the type of an inner class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183954)).

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes - you'll want to use `#` instead of `.`:

```
class A { class B }
val a : A.B = null
```

// error: not found: value A

```
val a : A#B = null
```

// works

The `.` syntax is used to refer to members of a specific instance of the outer class:

```
val a = new A
val b : a.B = null
```