# What does '#' mean in a type parameter?

Tags: scala, type-parameter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does one select Scala type members with a hash instead of a dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot)

I sometimes see a type parameter like:

```
class Test[K] {
  type T = Foo[K#Bar]
}
```

Can someone please explain what the '#' means in this type parameter ? Is it some kind of restriction for `K` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183954/referring-to-the-type-of-an-inner-class-in-scala

Answer (score 3):

No, the # is a type projection. In your case however that does not work because K does not define any BAR type.

```
trait A  { 
           type T 
           def apply():T 
}

trait MyClass[X<:A] { 
               type SomeType = X#T 
               def applySeq():Traversable[SomeType] 
}


class AImpl extends A { 
      type T=Int 
      def apply():Int = 10
}

class MyClassImpl extends MyClass[AImpl] {
         def applySeq(): Traversable[SomeType] = List(10)
}
```

That basically let you use the type T in A inside MyClass .

In fact, also the following compile:

```
class MyClassImpl extends MyClass[AImpl] {def applySeq(): Traversable[Int] = List(10)}
```

Answer (score 0):

'#' is used to project out a type enclosed in another type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6676210/402428) to the question ["Why does one select Scala type members with a hash instead of a dot"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot)?