# Play framework (2.3.5) - Template accessing an inner class fails

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a class defined like so (pseudo code):

```
package com.some.namespace

public class SomeClass {

    protected SomeClass() {}

    // stuff...

    public class SomeInnerClass {

        public SomeInnerClass() {}

        // more stuff (accesses instance variables from SomeClass)...

    }

}
```

Then in my template I use the reusable block defines like so:

```
@doSomething(val: com.some.namespace.SomeClass.SomeInnerClass) = {

    // even more stuff...

}
```

But I get the error:

> type SomeInnerClass is not a member of object
>   com.some.namespace.SomeClass

Am I not able to access inner classes within the templates or is this supposed to work? (if it is supposed to work I might need to post my actual code)

Comment: Doesn't your inner class need to be static? If it is it should work just like any other class.

Comment: I don't think so, `SomeClass`  is a singleton that I access in the view which has a list of the `SomeInnerClass` classes which I get via a getter and pass to the reusable block inside a for loop. In fact if I make the inner class static it will break my code as `SomeClass` is required to be an instance and therefore `SomeInnerClass` doesn't need (or want) to be static because it accesses instance variables from the `SomeClass` class, no?

Comment: Thank you for your edit @Mikesname i totally missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work, but because `SomeInnerClass` is a *dependent* type, i.e. dependent on your singleton outer class instance, you need to write it like:

```
@doSomething(value: com.some.namespace.SomeClass#SomeInnerClass) = {
    // even more stuff...
}
```

The `SomeClass#SomeInnerClass` syntax in Scala means, vaguely, a `SomeInnerClass` from *any instance of* `SomeClass`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184116/285374) for more detail.

If the inner class was **static**, however, your current `SomeClass.SomeInnerClass` syntax would be the way to go.