# Returning a list of inner class objects

Tags: scala

I'm coming from Java to Scala. I want to create an `Outer` class that defines (1) an inner `Inner` case class and (2) a method that returns a list of `Inner` objects. Note that in Java, the type of the inner class would unambiguously be `Outer.Inner`.

I found that there are two ways to reference the type of the inner class: `outerObject.Inner` or `Outer#Inner`, as discussed [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/inner-classes.html). **Which should I use to return a list of the Inner object?**

For example, I can implement my Scala code like this:

```
// Implementation 1
class Outer {
    case class Inner(id: String)
    def build(input: List[String]): List[Inner] = {
        var result = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Inner]()
        input.foreach { s =>
            val inner = Inner(s)
            result += inner
        }
        result.toList
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
// Implementation 2
class Outer {
    case class Inner(id: String)
    def build(input: List[String]): List[Outer#Inner] = {
        var result = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Outer#Inner]()
        input.foreach { s =>
            val inner = Inner(s)
            result += inner
        }
        result.toList
    }
}
```

where the only difference is that `build()` returns `List[Inner]` or `List[Outer#Inner]`.

Suppose the caller of my code runs this:

```
val input: List[String] = List("A", "B", "C")
val outer = new Outer()
val output = outer.build(input)
```

Then for implementation 1, the caller sees that output is:

```
output: List[outer.Inner] = List(Inner(A), Inner(B), Inner(C))
```

while for implementation 2, the caller sees:

```
output: List[Outer#Inner] = List(Inner(A), Inner(B), Inner(C))
```

Which is the preferred (idiomatic) approach in Scala?

Related questions:

- [Referring to the type of an inner class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183954/referring-to-the-type-of-an-inner-class-in-scala)
- [Why Inner Class in Scala is bound to Outer Class Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301149/why-inner-class-in-scala-is-bound-to-outer-class-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to *Scala*!

Firstly, there's a cleaner, more efficient way to create your implementations, which I've shown below.

```scala
// Implementation 1
class Outer {
  case class Inner(id: String)
  def build(input: List[String]): List[Inner] = input.map(s => Inner(s))
}

// Implementation 2
class Outer {
  case class Inner(id: String)
  def build(input: List[String]): List[Outer#Inner] = input.map(s => Inner(s))
}
```

The use of `map` means that you don't need any ugly `var` elements, and nor do you need to build a `ListBuffer` then convert that to a `List`.

As to which is more idiomatic, it depends upon what you're trying to do. The first form returns a *path-dependent* list of `Inner`s. It can be restricted for use with the `Outer` instance that created it. In the second form, the type of `Inner` returned cannot be tied to a specific `Outer` instance, but can be used anywhere that *any* `Inner` instance is acceptable. So, the latter is more restrictive and the former less so. Consider the following:

```scala
// Implementation 1
class Outer {
  case class Inner(id: String)
  def build(input: List[String]): List[Inner] = input.map(s => Inner(s))
  def getId(inner: Inner): String = inner.id
}

// Implementation 2
class Outer {
  case class Inner(id: String)
  def build(input: List[String]): List[Outer#Inner] = input.map(s => Inner(s))
  def getId(inner: Outer#Inner): String = inner.id
}
```

Then try evaluating the following with each implementation:

```scala
val input: List[String] = List("A", "B", "C")
val outer = new Outer()
val output = outer.build(input)
val outer2 = new Outer()
outer2.getId(output.head)
```

With *implementation 1*, you'll get a type mismatch error on the last statement, but you will not with *implementation 2*.

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention this (probably to avoid further confusion), but the *path-dependent* version is a sub-type of the general version. (That is `this.Inner` is a sub-type of `Outer#Inner`.) So you can pass a *path-dependent* version of `Inner` to a function requiring *any* `Inner`, but not the other way around.

That is, the following will work:

```scala
class Outer {
  case class Inner(id: String)
  def build(input: List[String]): List[Inner] = input.map(Inner)
  def getId(inner: Outer#Inner): String = inner.id
}

val input: List[String] = List("A", "B", "C")
val outer = new Outer()
val output = outer.build(input)
val outer2 = new Outer()
outer2.getId(output.head)
```

but this will not:

```scala
class Outer {
  case class Inner(id: String)
  def build(input: List[String]): List[Outer#Inner] = input.map(Inner)
  def getId(inner: Inner): String = inner.id
}

val input: List[String] = List("A", "B", "C")
val outer = new Outer()
val output = outer.build(input)
val outer2 = new Outer()
outer2.getId(output.head)
```

(Note that I also used an even terser form of the `build` method in each of these.)

So, to summarize...

Functions (belonging to `Outer`) that return new `Inner` instances should return the *path-dependent* form, since that is also a sub-type of the generic form, and provides maximum flexibility. (However, bear in mind that publicly accessible `Inner` class instances can be created from outside of the `Outer` instance's control, and can be of whatever type the caller requires.)

Of far greater significance, however, is the type signature that is used when accepting existing `Inner` instances:

- If the operation (belonging to an `Outer` instance) has a strong coupling between the `Inner` instance and itself (and the `Inner` instance will typically maintain a reference to its `Outer` instance), such that it would be an error to supply an `Inner` belonging to a different `Outer` instance, then you should only accept the *path-dependent* form.
- However, if the operation works for *any* `Inner` instance, including the case where the accepting method doesn't belong to `Outer` at all, then it should accept the generic form.

Comment: Thank you. What is the advantage of Scala's *path-dependent list of inner classes*? What problem does that solve?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 In this particular example, there's clearly no obvious benefit from using the _path dependent_ form. In fact, it probably causes more problems than it solves. However, each `Inner` is also linked to the `Outer` instance that it belongs to. Let's say that `Outer` has other data members that `Inner` is manipulating through that reference. If you pass an `Inner` created by one `Outer` instance to a different `Outer` instance, it is still accessing the original `Outer`'s members, which might be cause for confusion.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2694607/2593574) for a good example.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 There's also another way to declare _path-dependent_ types via the `type` statement, which does not necessarily rely on inner classes. See Chapter 20 (and 20.7 in particular) of _Programming in Scala_, Third Edition, by Odersky, Spoon & Venners.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Apologies for all the extra comments! :-) Just wanted to let you know that I updated the answer to better explain when to use each type. In practice, it should be pretty easy to make the necessary distinctions.